# AppModule is not an NgModule

Tags: angular, npm, ng-build

I keep getting this error when I run ng build.

I have tried deleting node_modules as well as global npm_cache directories and reinstalling. Most of the answers I've found to this problem are a couple years old, so downgrading typescript versions as one solutions suggests isn't an option.

I have tried this with typescript version 2.5.3 as well and that fails with the same error.

I also have teammates who can run ng build without a problem.

Any suggestions?

Angular version info:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.7
Node: 8.9.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 4.4.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
typescript: 2.3.4
webpack-sources: 1.0.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Package.json Info:

```
{
  "name": "jeweler-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "deploy": "ng build --base-href /jewelerapplication/ --deploy-url=/Content/jewelerapplication/",
    "devTeamDeploy": "ng build --base-href /jewelerapplication/ --deploy-url=/Content/JewelerApplication/ --e=devtest --output-hashing bundles --aot false --extractCss false --output-path=C:/Nuget/JewelerApplication",
    "teamdeploy": "ng build --base-href /jewelerapplication/ --deploy-url=/Content/JewelerApplication/ --prod --aot false --extractCss false --output-path=C:/Nuget/JewelerApplication",
    "watch": "ng build --extractCss false --watch --base-href /jewelerapplication/ --deploy-url=/Content/jewelerapplication/"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "angular2-pubsub": "~4.0.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "~8.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "~4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "~2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
    "install": "~0.10.1",
    "ng2-datepicker": "~1.8.3",
    "ng2-page-scroll": "~4.0.0-beta.7",
    "ng2-responsive": "~0.8.4",
    "ng2-semantic-ui": "~0.9.6",
    "npm": "~5.4.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "simple-line-icons": "~2.4.1",
    "text-mask-addons": "~3.5.1",
    "webpack-sources": "~1.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.68",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "~0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.2",
    "tslint": "~5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

Error Details:

```
ERROR in Error: AppModule is not an NgModule
at _getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Repository\Premier Designs\jewelerapplication\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:140:15)
at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Repository\Premier Designs\jewelerapplication\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\Repository\Premier Designs\jewelerapplication\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Repository\Premier Designs\jewelerapplication\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Repository\Premier Designs\jewelerapplication\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:240:66)
at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Repository\Premier Designs\jewelerapplication\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:493:24)
at <anonymous>
```